# Coffee processing methode and filter brewing guide

Tags: paper-filter

I just recently stuck into paper filter brewing and was frustated about the brewing process of a different kind of coffee processing method( wine, natural, honey, etc).
Can someone please share their experience about the different method of brewing that you think is optimal for each beans processing methode ( grain size, temperature, brewing steps).

Comment: Hi, I couldn't understand what you are really asking for. Could you please elaborate? Do you want to learn whether coffee processing methods has any effect on filter coffee brewing?

Comment: Welcome! Please take the [tour] and browse through our [help], especially [answer], to learn more about how the site works. If you are asking for a detailed comparison of multiple aspects, I’m afraid that this is too broad for this site. But overall, I agree with @MTSan that your question needs more details and clarification - please [edit] your post and help us help you, thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, but yes thats exactly what i want to know

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to adjust your brewing process for each coffee individually and sometimes might even tweak and change it slightly as your coffee ages. Even if some coffees might be from the same region with the same process and similar roast, their optimal brewing process can vary wildly.

For filter (I assume you're using a V60 or something similar), I'd recommend the following parameters as a starting point:

- 97°C Water (Or boiling if your kettle doesn't have precise temperature control - the key thing is that you use the same temperature from brew to brew)
- Grind size such that you get a total brew time of 2min 30s
- 60g of coffee per 1000g (e.g. 15g to 250g) of water

After you've brewed the coffee, there is no way around using your taste to adjust the parameters. For starters, try to keep everything the same except your grind size.

If your coffee is underextracted and tastes acidic, try grinding finer so you increase extraction and extraction time. If your coffee is overextracted and tastes bitter, try grinding coarser so that you decrease the extraction and extraction time.

This compass by Barista Hustle might help you find what you need to adjust to get the kind of taste you want.

[image: Barista Hustle Compass]

There is also an [updated and interactive version](https://www.baristahustle.com/blog/coffee-compass/) of that compass available.

Comment: I don't see how the compass adds much value here. If you know your problem is "underextracted" then it's not a big leap to the fix of "extract more". I would think that "recognizing these things as being under extracted vs being weak" would be a more useful thing to learn.